# Being an EEC member, what will Norway gain and lose if it decides to join the EU?

Tags: european-union, europe, norway

Specifically, what rights does a non-EU member in the EEC not have? And what restrictions can it avoid being out of the EU but in the EEC?

Comment: Weirdly it came up in the related links, but didn't come back in the search bar when trying to flag the duplicate. I had to use the threadID to link them.

Comment: The other question doesn't address what Norway would gain by entering the EU.

Comment: @Relaxed: I agree, but to keep answers from duplicating material on the other page, it would be better if this question was edited to focus on the gains.

Comment: Do you actually mean Norway is a member of the EEA? Norway doesn't seem to have been a member of the EEC, while that org existed as such. ("The Norwegian people had finally rejected membership in a referendum on 25 September 1972"). And of course they later (1994) rejected EU membership as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it would gain: A direct influence on EU policy (concretely that means a seat at the Council and a permanent representative but also a Commissioner, judges at the EU courts, EU civil servants, etc.) that it must implement anyway. Right now, Norway is effectively a rule taker.

What it would lose: Independent fisheries policy. There would probably be a few other adjustments, maybe some budget contributions and of course an apparent loss of sovereignty but the main thing is clearly the fisheries.

Comment: Is the size of the Norway payments the same as their EU contributions would be as a full member? The financial payments have been a big talking point throughout the Brexit period.

Comment: @Jontia I have been wondering myself. I am not aware of any professional simulation and it's difficult to work out exactly. I suspect it would pay more into the EU budget but it would also get more of this money back. Ultimately, I suspect they would pay quite a bit more (in net terms). As a back of the envelope calculation, taking the overall Norwegian contribution to the Norway and EEA grants for 2009-2014 works out to about €65 per year and per person. That compares to a net UK contribution of €113 per person for 2017.

Comment: But, everything else being equal, Norway would pay more than that as it is richer and wouldn't enjoy a rebate, perhaps something like the €200/inhabitant paid by Denmark (so potentially between two and three times as much as now).